# When a method depends on another method

Tags: javascript

What is the best way to deal with the following situation in JavaScript.

I have three methods (`m1`, `m2`, `m3`) and the last one (`m3`) depends from the results of the others two (`m1`, `m2`).

In this way it works, but I am curious to know if there is a better way to write the code in this situation, especially for future developers that will read the code.

```
var O = function () {
    this.p = 0;
}

O.prototype.makesomething = function () {
    var that = this;
    that.m1();
    that.m2();
    that.m3();
}

O.prototype.m1 = function () {O.p++}; // it changes the value O.p
O.prototype.m2 = function () {O.p++}; // it changes the value O.p
O.prototype.m3 = function () {return O.p}; // m3 depends by m1, m2 because it needs to get the update value of O.p
```

Comment: Will you always have to call these three functions in this particular order? Or can you call m1, m2, and m3 in different orders, or not all three at once?

Comment: I rewrite the code; by the way if I read the following code I can suppose that m1, m2, and m3 are independent; but acutally m3 is not, so how can I make it explicit?

Comment: It's not obvious from the code you provided, how exactly O.p is changing? Mind providing minimal working code example, the expected behaviour, and what's going wrong.

Comment: I don't know if those comments next to the function definitions were just to help explain your question, but in your real code definitely add a comment that makes it clear m3 must be called after the other two, that's the first and easiest thing you can do to help people reading the code in the future. If the functions are always called in that order you could make them private functions either within `makesomething` or within a new `doM1M2M3` function that can be called from `makesomething` and other places. Or call m3 from inside m2.

Comment: So maybe the best way will be by using the callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I don't know for sure, but putting `this.p = 0` inside `O` does not make sense in combination with `O.p`. You probably mean `this.p` inside `m3`, when referring to the instance.

Anyway, if you are looking for readability, you could make some simple but idiomatic functions like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ZvprZ/1/.

```
var O = function () {
    this.p = 0;
}

O.prototype.makesomething = function () {
    var that = this;

    var result = when( that.m1(), that.m2() )
                .then( that.m3() );

    return result;
}

O.prototype.m1 = function () {this.p++};
O.prototype.m2 = function () {this.p++};
O.prototype.m3 = function () {return this.p};
```

The `when`/`then` can be rather straight-forward since it does not do anything than making it more readable:

```
(function(window) {
    var when, then, o;

    when = function() {
        return o; // just return the object so that you can chain with .then,
                  // the functions have been executed already before executing
                  // .when
    };

    then = function(a) {
        return a; // return the result of the first function, which has been
                  // executed already (the result is passed)
    };

    o = { when: when,
          then: then };

    window.when = when; // expose
    window.then = then;
})(window);
```